# Method to preload Android internal storage with files

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-internal-storage

I'm using `FileProvider` to share files with other apps. I need to include these files with the apk. Since `FileProvider` gets files from internal storage `/data/data/<pkg-name>`, is there a way to preload these files?  So far the only method I found is to first include the files in the raw/assets directory, then programmatically move the files over to internal storage.
Is this the only way, or is there a better recommended method?  Can FileProvider transfer files from the assets directory?

Comment: This may help you. CWAC-Provider
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider

Comment: Why can't you download them from some server when application is starting for first time? There is no point in including file in your app if it is not part of resources, all files can be downloaded and saved into any folder you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `FileProvider` to transfer file from Asset Directory. You will have  to implement your own `ContentProvider`.

Here are similar questions with answers that can help you:

- [Share Assets Using fileprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555722/share-assets-using-fileprovider#31586010)
- [android share images from assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888718/android-share-images-from-assets-folder)

You can also use *CWAC-Provider* which offers a class that handles Assets: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/blob/master/provider/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/provider/StreamProvider.java

Answer (score 0):

A different approach may be the usage of APK Expansion Files: [Expansion Files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

It allows you to ship additional files with your app, especially if your APK hit the 100 MB limit.

Expansion files are saved in the following path: `<shared-storage>/Android/obb/<package-name>/`, which can be retrieved via [getObbDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getObbDir()).